# EDITED How to get the json value for localStorage in a loop

Tags: javascript, json, cordova, local-storage

**after Oyeme's advise, i have changed my code, but still cannot work. it can alert "testing" but cannot alert DBuser_name .**

By the following coding, i can create a content like the image below. My problem is that, if the user click one of the people in the list, i would like to extract the  `student.data.user_name` into localStorage. however, in my coding below, seems that i did wrong?

```
function getStudentList() {
$.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/getStudents.php?jsoncallback=?', function(data) {
    $('#studentList li').remove();
    $('#load').hide();
    //students = data.user_name;
    $.each(data, function(index, student) {
        //$('#studentList').append('<li><a href="tutor_student_detail.html?user_name=' + student.data.user_name + '">' +
        $('#studentList').append('<li><a href="tutor_student_detail.html">' +
                '<h4>' + student.data.user_name + '</h4>' +
                '<p>' + student.data.role + '</p>' +
                '</a></li>');
                
        $("li a").click(function() {
       window.localStorage["view"] = $(this).data('user_name');
    });
    });
    $('#studentList').listview('refresh');
});
```

}

Below are the coding of tutor_student_detail.html (js part)

```
function start(){

var localUsername=window.localStorage.getItem("view");
    
$.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/getStudent.php?user_name='+localUsername+'&jsoncallback=?', displayStudent);
    
    alert("testing");
}

function displayStudent(data) {
    var DBuser_name=data[0].data.user_name;
    alert(DBuser_name);
    var employee = data.item;
    $('#username').text(student.data.user_name);
    $('#pw').text(student.data.password);
    $('#id').text(student.data.id);
    

    $('#actionList').listview('refresh');
    
}
```

the output of json string is something like

> ?([{"data":{"id":"4","user_name":"studentB","book":"4567","role":"Student"}}]);

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#studentList').append('<li><a href="tutor_student_detail.html"
                 data-name="'+student.data.user_name+'">' +
                '<h4>' + student.data.user_name + '</h4>' +
                '<p>' + student.data.role + '</p>' +
                '</a></li>');

$("li a").click(function() {
   window.localStorage["view"] = $(this).data('name');
});
```

Comment: still not work, would you please hv a look on my latest version above

Comment: Did you forget to add  this line data-name="'+student.data.user_name+'">' to a li?